# Phantomas not render page directly which the page url contains hashmark

Tags: phantomjs

I'm testing a webpage by using phantomas,but I found the problem when I use the url contains hashmark such as 'http://bookstore2.shuqireader.com/route.php?sq_pg_param=bsbc&ver=151011#!/bid/3379630/'.

The screenshot of this page in Phantomas is all about blank,but it work perfectly by using PhantomJs alone.

I installed Phantomas by 'npm install'

```
phantoms http://bookstore2.shuqireader.com/route.php?sq_pg_param=bsbc&ver=151011#!/bid/3379630/ --screenshot=saveimg.png
```

saveimg.png is all blank

```
var webPage = require('webpage'); 
var page = webPage.create(); 

page.customHeaders = { 
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0; en-us; GT-I9300 Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30" 
}; 

page.open('http://bookstore2.shuqireader.com/route.php?   sq_pg_param=bsbc&ver=151011#!/bid/3379630/', function (status) { 
    if(status=="success"){ 
        page.render('saveimg.png'); 
    } 
        phantom.exit(); 
});
```

in phantomJs way, saveimg.png is normal

Is it a bug?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the url in quotes on the commandline? Also, I don't see plain PhantomJS produce any meaningful image, because there are a couple of spaces in the middle of the url.

Comment: Oh,sorry,never mind those spaces.I tried it,also used urlencode,but still not working

Comment: Have you used `"` or `'`? Try both.

Comment: both `"` and `'`,I reported this as a bug for phantomas project,see https://github.com/macbre/phantomas/issues/576 I'll try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you want, but generally all these NPM wrappers of PhantomJs suck for various reasons,  the authors generally only handle specifically their use case and the packages fail others who have slightly different needs.

Usually they fail for performance reasons (no problem if you are OK maxing out a CPU every request)  but as you see, sometimes you'll be caught by situations the authors didn't code for.

You are much better off just writing your launching phantomjs.exe as a child process.  Another alternative is to use the api at http://api.PhantomJsCloud.com (disclosure: I made it)